# OpenFire: Hide all users in the same group from each other?

Tags: openfire

We would like to restrict access to users within a group (*Staff*) so that they can only see/chat with users from another group (*Support*) and not each other. We would also like to ensure that users from the *Support* group can see all those in the *Staff* group.

Can this be achieved and if so, how?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this using the [Packet Filter Plugin](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins/packetfilter/readme.html), which is available by default in the Plugins section of the OpenFire admin. Using this plugin you can block messages between users of the *Staff* group from chatting with or seeing each other.

I'd post a screen shot and detailed instructions, but it seems like Ignite Realtime's site is down at the moment. I'll post back when they fix it.

**EDIT:** This works, I just tested it. Here's what you'll do:

1. Install the Packet Filter Plugin from the "Plugins" tab of the OpenFire admin:
   [image: Install It!]
2. Make sure you have your "Staff" and "Support" groups set up.
   [image: I Have Groupies!]
3. Go to the "Packet Filter Rules" under "Server", "Server Settings"
   [image: Time to Filter!]
4. Create a new rule to `Pass` `Any` messages from `Group` `Staff` to `Group` `Support`:
   [image: This is the rule!]
5. Then create a new rule to `Drop` `Any` messages from `Group` `Staff` to `Group` `Staff`. You should then have the following two rules:
   [image: You're Done!]

You can optionally enable logging if you wish.

Now, any time a user from the **Staff** group tries to get the presence of or send a message to any other user from the **Staff** group, these messages will be dropped and the two will be unable to unable to see or chat with each other. However, messages from the **Staff** group to the **Support** group will be passed along.

You could chose in the second rule to `Drop` *all* messages from the **Staff** group if you choose. This will prevent them from communicating with *anyone* not in the **Support** group.

I hope this helps!

Comment: This works, I just tested it. Editing my answer now...

Comment: Works perfectly. Just want to add; doing the same with `presence` means staff can't *see* each-other, either. Which helps against "I can see them, but I can't message them" confusion.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a single account for the staff? You can set Openfire to allow accounts to be used from multiple locations. Then, when an user of the Support group will want to reach someone of the staff, the message will be displayed on all clients with the staff account enabled. So nobody of the staff will miss a request and they won't be able to talk each other with this single account.

Comment: Unfortunately this wouldn't work. Messages from support need to be targeted to individual staff members and could contain semi-sensitive information.